# How to isolate h in this situation.

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

Using the definition of derivative $lim h\rightarrow0$ of $(f(x+h)-(fx))/h,$ how to calculate :

$x^7+\sqrt{7x}-1/\pi+1$

I don't know how to isolate $h$  inside the root to cancel with the denominator. After expand, i can cancel some terms, but have this$ sqrt(7x+7h).$

Comment: What $h{}{}{}$?

Comment: May we suppose that you want to compute the derivative of the expression from definition ?

Comment: There is a standard trick of multiplying top and bottom by the conjugate of the top for differentiating square roots.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to compute $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac {\sqrt{7x+h}-\sqrt {7x}}h$  Try multiplying top and bottom by the conjugate $\sqrt{7x+h}+\sqrt {7x}$